# Import Stack Overflow data dump into MySQL

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-explorer, data-dump

I have downloaded the latest Stack Overflow data-dump (march 2013) from the ClearBits website:

http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump

I am trying to import this data dump into MySQL on my Mac (MAMP). This seems more complicated than I expected. I have seen some Python scripts that were used on early versions of the database, or softwares that can only be run on windows and have not been tested on new versions of the dump.

I am not a programmer. How would you advise me to import the data dump into MySQL? Do you know of a version that is already converted?

EDIT: I disagree, this question is not a duplicate, it's an update. The question you say I duplicated was posted 4 years ago. The torrent in the link does not even work. The database has a different structure now. I think it would be interesting to keep this question up to see if someone, over the course of the past 4 years (!), found an easier way to import the data dump into mysql.

Comment: Regarding the dupe, in those cases the older question can be updated with new answers. I've started a bounty to hopefully get the desired attention and answers.